# Why do I have to use the product rule instead of the chain rule when deriving the equation y = csc(x + cot(x))

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried deriving $y = csc(x+cotx)$ using the chain rule which gives me the following answer:

$$
\left(\csc^2\left(x\right)-1\right)\cot\left(\cot\left(x\right)+x\right)\csc\left(\cot\left(x\right)+x\right)
$$

The online derivative calculator, [agrees](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=csc%28x%2Bcot%28x%29%29) with my answer.

However, according to my homework the answer is wrong, and instead utilises the product rule, giving the answer $ y' = -csc(x)cot(x)[x+2cot(x)] $

My question is, why is the chain rule not applicable here? Why would I have to use the product rule instead?

Comment: What you did is fine. The answer to your homework is wrong.

Comment: I believe you or the problem might have made a typo. The answer according to your homework appears to be the derivative of $\csc(x)(x+\cot(x))$